# Why can't I "freopen" a "tmpfile"?

Tags: c, docker, temporary-files

I tried to compile and run C code that has the following lines:

```
FILE *preproc_producer = NULL;
preproc_producer = tmpfile();
// preproc_producer is not NULL here
preproc_producer = freopen(NULL, "r+", preproc_producer);
// preproc_producer is NULL here
```

However, when running the code, `preproc_producer` ends up `NULL`, and error code is `Stale NFS file handle`

1. What is the issue with the above code?
2. What is the purpose of the `freopen` call here? I commented out the `freopen` line and the rest of the program seems to be working.

I'm using GCC 4.7.2, running Ubuntu 64 12.04 inside a Docker 0.6.7 Linux container. The above code seems to work outside the Docker container.

**Update:** strace dump:

```
stat("/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
gettimeofday({1385247432, 199732}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 127
open("/tmp/tmpf9l14HD", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
unlink("/tmp/tmpf9l14HD")               = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
brk(0)                                  = 0xc94000
brk(0xcb5000)                           = 0xcb5000
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7afb9d0000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lstat("/proc/self/fd/3", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0700, st_size=64, ...}) = 0
munmap(0x7f7afb9d0000, 4096)            = 0
open("/proc/self/fd/3", O_RDWR)         = -1 ESTALE (Stale NFS file handle)
```

Comment: NULL means failure, otherwise, the returned stream pointer is already "open"... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/tmpfile/

Comment: run your program in `strace` and see what happens. I'd not expect this to work if freopen() have to close the file to change the access mode, as a tmpfile() is deleted when it is closed.

Comment: Take a look at the POSIX specification for [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html). You should set `errno = 0;` before making the call and examine `errno` afterwards when the reopen fails to determine why it failed.  Superficially, there's no reason why the code should not work; equally, there's no obvious reason why you'd need the `freopen()` in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

From the C99 standard:

> The freopen function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by filename
> and associates the stream pointed to by stream with it. The mode argument is used just
> as in the fopen function.
>
> If filename is a null pointer, the freopen function attempts to change the mode of
> the stream to that specified by mode, as if the name of the file currently associated with
> the stream had been used. It is implementation-defined which changes of mode are
> permitted (if any), and under what circumstances.

So, probably who wrote this code meant to change the temporary file open mode from `w+b` to `r+` (which mostly boils down to change the stream to text mode). Unfortunately, it seems that in your implementation it's not possible to change the open mode of a temporary file in that way.

I suppose that it may come from the fact that closing a temporary file also deletes it, but it may also be that `glibc` implementation of `freopen` doesn't support mode changes in `freopen` (the manpage doesn't even mention the possibility to pass `NULL` as first argument).

Comment: indeed. freopen() in glibc documents that it closes the existing stream. Which means for a tmpfile() the file gets deleted too.

Comment: I added the strace. The fail is on `open("/proc/self/fd/3", O_RDWR)`. Perhaps this is a file system issue?